# Using value of a table as color indicator for \addplot like a colormap

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to use a relative value (percentage) extracted of a table to define the color of several 2D plots like this:

[image: Sample plot with different colors]

At the moment I'm using `addplot[mesh]` together with a self defined colormap but I'd rather prefer a different way as `mesh` doesn't work with some modifications I want to do later.

```
\addplot[mesh,point meta=\yValRel,point meta min={0}, point meta max={100}] table [x=x\datasetNumber, y=F\datasetNumber] {\dataXF} ;
```

I would prefer something like this, where the value read from the table is directly used as an relative operator for the colormapping:

```
\addplot[color=orange! \yValRel !blue] table [x=x\rowNumber, y=F\rowNumber] {\dataXF};
```

This command works with pre-defined variables, but `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yValRel}{\pgfplotsretval}` doesn't read the value during the loop (when printing the number with `node at (axis:cs 3,\yValRel) {\yValRel};` it prints always the same number).

Has anyone a proper solution? Below you find a working minimum example. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{colormap={blueorange}{color(0)=(blue); color(100)=(orange);}}
\pgfplotstableread{
    x0  F0  x1  F1  x2  F2
    1   10  1   10  1   40
    2   20  2.5 15  1.5 30
    3   30  3.5 25  1.8 20
    4   40  4   40  4.8 15
    5   50  5   45  5   10
}\dataXF    
\pgfplotstableread{
    0   40  80
}\dataY

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[colormap name=blueorange]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,...,0}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\datasetNumber}{#1}

    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index] \datasetNumber}\of\dataY
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yValRel}{\pgfplotsretval}

    %\addplot[color=orange! \yValRel !blue] table [x=x\rowNumber, y=F\rowNumber] {\dataXF};
    \addplot[mesh,point meta=\yValRel,point meta min={0}, point meta max={100}] table [x=x\datasetNumber, y=F\datasetNumber] {\dataXF} ;
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\pgfplotstablegetelem` and `\addplot` commands are executed at different times (even though they're both within `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`), so the value of `\yValRel` is not updated for each plot. You can wrap your code into a `.code` key that you put in your `\addplot` options, which makes sure that the commands get executed at the right time.

For example, you could write a style

```
\pgfplotsset{
    make value available/.code args={#1 of #2}{
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index] #1}\of#2
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yValRel}{\pgfplotsretval}
    }
}
```

which you then call using

```
\addplot[make value available=#1 of \dataY,color=orange!\yValRel!blue] ...
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{
    make value available/.code args={#1 of #2}{
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index] #1}\of#2
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yValRel}{\pgfplotsretval}
    }
}
\pgfplotstableread{
    x0  F0  x1  F1  x2  F2
    1   10  1   10  1   40
    2   20  2.5 15  1.5 30
    3   30  3.5 25  1.8 20
    4   40  4   40  4.8 15
    5   50  5   45  5   10
}\dataXF    
\pgfplotstableread{
    0   40  80
}\dataY

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[colormap name=blueorange]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,...,0}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\datasetNumber}{#1}

    \addplot[make value available=#1 of \dataY,color=orange!\yValRel!blue] table [x=x\datasetNumber, y=F\datasetNumber] {\dataXF};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks heaps! is it possible not to use `make value available=#1` but `make value available=\somevariable` without having the problem of different execution levels as well?

Comment: Hm, I can't see a straightforward solution. Probably best to post a new question, Ryan Reich might be able to help out with that.