# Using addplot and pgfmathresult for color

Tags: pgfplotstable, pgfmathparse

I could use some help. I am trying to color a bar chart assigning different colors using a foreach loop and pgfmathresult to get a color gradient. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
Label 1 2 3
R1 3 2 1
R2 2 1 3
R3 1 2 3
}\testdata

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked, ymin=0, xtick=data, xticklabels from table={\testdata}{Label}]
\foreach \s in {1,...,3}{
    \pgfmathparse{\s*30}
    \addplot [fill=blue!\pgfmathresult!green] table [y=\s, meta=Label,x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But the result I obtain has no gradient

:[image]

Jet when I run almost the same code (without pgfplot):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \s in {1,...,3} {
    \pgfmathparse{(\s*30)}
 \draw[blue!\pgfmathresult!green, thick]
(0,\s * .2) -- (1,\s * .2)
;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the desired gradient:
[image]

Has anyone an idea whats going wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: I guess addplot changes the value of pgfmathresult while working with it. Try  temporarily  store the value to something else.

Comment: [tikz pgf - Store \pgfmathresult in a variable - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18771/store-pgfmathresult-in-a-variable)

Comment: Looks like that isn't the cause however...

Comment: This seems quite promising but I cant get it to work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59817/using-value-of-a-table-as-color-indicator-for-addplot-like-a-colormap?rq=1

Comment: Okay I figure out the solution, turns out the thing stores the content verbatim until the end of the block before expanding the content inside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand `pgfmathresult` before passing it to `\addplot`. To inject the expanded value inside the command, one way is to use a common idiom [LaTeX3 - Expand nested argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/640324/250119)

(side note, `addplot` will eventually expand it, but only at the end; thus all the colors get expanded to the same value)

```
\def\plotcommand#1{
    \addplot [fill=blue!#1!green] table [y=\s, meta=Label,x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked, ymin=0, xtick=data, xticklabels from table={\testdata}{Label}]
\foreach \s in {1,...,3}{
    \pgfmathparse{\s*30}
    \expandafter\plotcommand\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note

0. <s>I'm not that familiar with TikZ, maybe TikZ offer a built-in solution that is easier to read.</s>  On reading the questions below I'm pretty convinced that it isn't really possible to be cleaner.
1. With a new LaTeX kernel you can `\ExpandArgs{V}\plotcommand\pgfmathresult`, see [How do I have to invoke \expandafter for a macro with multiple arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133753/250119)
2. If you put the `plotcommand` command definition inside the foreach you need to double the `#` because of some weird `foreach` command "bug" <sub>I can find [Having trouble with Tikz and Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234719/250119) which is similar but not exactly the same</sub>
3. If you don't mind using heavy package for a one-off task I'd recommend my package

```
\usepackage{execinside}

[... common preamble ...]


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked, ymin=0, xtick=data, xticklabels from table={\testdata}{Label}]
\foreach \s in {1,...,3}{
    \pgfmathparse{\s*30}
    \execinside{
        \addplot [fill=blue!\EIexpand\pgfmathresult!green] table [y=\s, meta=Label,x expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
    }
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

Similar questions:

- [How to use a command inside \addplot options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393934/how-to-use-a-command-inside-addplot-options)
- [Changing colors in Pgfplots using \foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591015/changing-colors-in-pgfplots-using-foreach)
- [Change color in addplot in for loop of pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305175/change-color-in-addplot-in-for-loop-of-pgfplots)
- [PGFplots - `\addplot` and `\foreach` won't compile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557767/pgfplots-addplot-and-foreach-wont-compile)
- [Using pgfplots, why do I get "undefined control sequence" when trying to use a foreach variable as a parameter to addplot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69445/using-pgfplots-why-do-i-get-undefined-control-sequence-when-trying-to-use-a-f/71199#71199)

Comment: I don't think pgfplotsforeach is useful in this case because pgfmathresult is not directly substituted in.

Comment: I just found out that the edef thing is an "official trick" recommended by pgf manual https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525053/expansion-of-addplot-and-draw-are-different-in-tikz/525107?noredirect=1#comment1328411_525107 so even more likely for this one to be official.